# Is it possible to define the same code for multiple methods more efficiently in Java?

Tags: java, performance, javafx

I'm trying to define the same behaviour for two different interaction events on a JavaFX ComboBox. To do this, I first call

```
targetIDCombo.setOnKeyReleased(keyEvent -> {
    targetIDCombo.setValue(targetIDCombo.getEditor().getText());
    updateConnectBtnText(targetIDCombo.getValue());
});
```

and then

```
targetIDCombo.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
    targetIDCombo.setValue(targetIDCombo.getEditor().getText());
    updateConnectBtnText(targetIDCombo.getValue());
});
```

Clearly the two listeners execute the same code. Therefore, is it possible to do this in such a way that I define my desired behaviour once, and then provide it to both listeners at the same time in order to have more efficient code, per se?

Something like

```
defineBehaviour(targetIDCombo::setOnKeyReleased, targetIDCombo::setOnAction, Controller::comboBoxAction)
```

where the `defineBehaviour()` method will assign `comboBoxAction()` to both action events for `targetIDCombo`

Comment: work through a tutorial about java (or any) language basics and apply what you learned

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU you want this:

```
targetIDCombo.setOnKeyReleased(keyEvent -> {
    defineBehaviour(targetIDCombo);
});


targetIDCombo.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
    defineBehaviour(targetIDCombo)
});

void defineBehaviour(ComboBox comboBox) {
    comboBox.setValue(comboBox.getEditor().getText());
    updateConnectBtnText(comboBox.getValue());
}
```

Comment: This is closer to what I want, thanks. However, my primary concern is this: is there no way to avoid calling setOnKeyReleased() and setOnAction() separately?

Comment: @A.P.Roblem why?

Comment: @kleopatra more for interest's sake than anything else. I'm aware of the basic approach as put forward by me or Peter, but it occurred to me that perhaps there was a way to streamline the process. When Google failed to turn up anything useful, I thought I'd ask here